# How do I stop jittery movement in Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My 2D game is not lagging, but for some reason the entire game world (except the player) is jittering when the player/camera moves. I tried parenting the camera to the Player and I tried using a script to make the camera move to the player, but it didn't help. It is worse if the framerate is lower, or if there are little frame drops. I use velocity to move the player. Using FixedUpdate (for the player and the camera) didn't help either, it just makes my player not jump every time I press the jump button. I tried searching but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not clear how you're moving objects, but the classic problem here is using a camera, which updates on `Update`, to view physics objects, which update on `FixedUpate`. The solution is generally to tick the "interpolate" box on the rigidbodies, but if you want anything more specific than that you'll need to add a lot more details regarding what specifically is jittering, how you're moving that, how you're moving the camera, the settings you've selected for any rigidbodies, and whether you're moving objects in `Update` or `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: I am not sure how to describe it, but everything seems to "jitter" and it hurts on the eyes, it only happens when moving. I set the velocity of the rigidbody when i want to move the player or jump, the camera is a child of the player so it follows around. The ground is a tilemap that has a composite collider, rigidbody, platform effector and tilemap collider. I tried setting the rb of the tilemap to interpolate, or setting the player rb to interpolate, but it didn't solve the problem. I have other tilemaps that act as a background and they don't have a rb, but they "jitter" aswell.

Comment: Also, the game is just a basic 2D platformer game and it's my first Unity game, so maybe I'm doing some beginner mistake?

Comment: @Chuck I put the fixed timestep to 0.01666 because my game is set to run at 60fps and changed the player movement Update method to fixedUpdate, now it's running really smooth. But if there is a short framedrop (55-58 fps), it jitters a lot. Even if I set the rigidbody of the player to interpolate, it doesn't help.

Comment: This is my player movement script for the x axis (inside fixedUpdate):

`rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this is a really difficult and tedious problem to troubleshoot.

I've had issues previously with moving a game object by transform that had a rigidbody.

I've had issues where a rigidbody parent had a child with a rigidbody - also never do this, each hierarchy should have one and only one rigidbody, and that should be at the root level. A rigidbody will "inherit" or consider colliders at all levels at or below the rigidbody in the hierarchy.

I've had issues with a rigidbody that didn't have a collider.

I've had issues where the camera was attached to the rigidbody.

I've had issues where the interpolation settings were not set.

I'd really need to browse through the project and look at the setup to give any kind of specific feedback. Otherwise I'll say that rigidbodies and rigidbody motion is such a pain in the ass that I would recommend NOT using them unless you absolutely have to.

You can do collision checks as triggers without rigidbodies. You can code your own movement and gravity system pretty easily for 2D. The only thing you really need physics for is if you want to solve physics-based collisions, and there I would again say don't use it if you can help it. You can also programmatically add a rigidbody, like for a combat knockout, and add the knockout force and direction, but all the rest of the combat is using scripted motions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I kind of figured it out by now. I changed the camera script so it follows the player smoothly and used interpolation for the player. My problem was the camera, it moved jittery because the Player has a Rigidbody and it was following the player every frame. If you look at the player closely now, it barely jitters anymore. It's not perfect but I guess it doesn't work better than that.

Comment: @xJuice - This is what I mentioned in my [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028664/how-do-i-stop-jittery-movement-in-unity-game/74076008?noredirect=1#comment130714274_74028664) - "the classic problem here is using a camera, which updates on `Update`, to view physics objects, which update on `FixedUpate`." It's honestly such a pain that I really, really try to avoid using Unity physics. Glad you found a solution that works for you!